# Stability? Can windows scheduler tasks run indefinitely

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I've set up 2 windows scheduled tasks to run indefinitely.

The advantage of having them in the scheduler is that we have other, period-triggered tasks (e.g. once-a-day, once-a-minute) set up in the scheduler, and these 2 tasks that run indefinitely are a depenedency for the others.

Each of the 2 tasks has it's own log file which I can view, and they are running fine for about a week now.

Question - Are jobs that run indefinitely in windows scheduler stable over the long term?

Can anyone share experiences?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems interesting - maybe it was downvoted because they thought this should go on another site, such as SuperUser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer this question, I've now had some scheduled tasks running in windows task scheduler for about 3 weeks and they have been perfectly stable for the whole time.

No crashes, no weird hangups, the java programs keep running and I can see from the logs (which roll each day) that they are healthy.